# This map defined on the infinite direct sum $H$ of Hilbert spaces is not in $L(H,H)$ after all

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification

Consider the direct sum $H:=\bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty H_n$ of the family $\{ H_n \}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of Hilbert spaces.

Let 
$$
             T:H\rightarrow H \\
               x\mapsto (T_1x_1, T_2x_2,...)
$$
where $T_n\in L(H_n,H_n)$ for all $n$.

I want to know if $T\in L(H,H)$.

I think I proved linearity, but I am not very sure of what I can do when dealing with infinite direct sums of vector spaces. Here it is:

Let $x,y\in H$.
$$
            T(x+y)= T((x_1+y_1,x_2+y_2,...))=(T_1(x_1+y_1),...)= \\
             = (T_1x_1+T_1y_1,...)=(T_1x_1,T_2x_2,...)+(T_1y_1,T_2x_2,...)=\\
             = Tx+Ty
$$
Now let $a\in \mathbb{C}$.
$$
                T(ax)=T((ax_1,ax_2,...))=(T_1(ax_1),T_2(ax_2),...)=\\
                     =(aT_1x_1,aT_2x_2,...)=aTx
$$
So this was easy. 
I still have to prove that $T$ is bounded (or, if it's not, to give a counterexample).

So I want to prove that there is some $C\in \mathbb{R^+}$ such that $\parallel Tx  \parallel = (\sum_{n=1}^\infty\parallel T_nx_n \parallel_n^2)^{1/2} \le C \parallel x \parallel = C(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\parallel x_n \parallel_n^2)^{1/2} $.

It seems to me that that is no such $C$,because even though all the $T_n$ are bounded, there are infinitely many of them, and so the $C_n$ can increase indefinitely, leaving $T$ unbounded. The counterexample I was thinking of:
$$
                  T_n=n\cdot I_n
$$
Clearly 
$$
   \parallel Tx  \parallel = (\sum_{n=1}^\infty\parallel T_nx_n  \parallel_n^2)^{1/2}= (\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\parallel x_n \parallel_n^2)^{1/2}
$$
is bigger than any $C$, for any non-zero $x\in H$.

Am I think of this correctly? It is still a little foggy to me.

Comment: You are right. $T$ need not be continuous.

Comment: It's usually seen as an exercise that $T$ is bounded if and only if $\sup_n\|T_n\|<\infty$.

Comment: @user251257 and is the counterexample correct?

Comment: @Simoes not quite. You need to give a sequence $X_m\in H$ such that $\|TX_m\| / \|X_m\|$ is unbounded.